# Failed to run schedule job via Crontab in Python Macbook air

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks

I tried to schedule my Python script to have daily run via cron but failed, may I know what's error here in my MacBook?

1. type crontab -e in terminal
2. copy the below code to crontab

   ```
   38 22 * * 0-6 $(which python3) /Users/mrcheung/Desktop/Python/Stock_Monitoring/Stock_monitoring_students_v6_lesson_2020.py
   ```
3. save the job to type :wq

However, I can't wait the job is running, is there any missing step or syntax error?

```
0 22 * * 0-6 /Users/mrcheung/Desktop/Python/Stock_Monitoring/Stock_monitoring_students_v6_lesson_2020.py
You have mail in /var/mail/mrcheung
bash-3.2$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see here for [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks but may I know the question is deleted already?

Comment: it's not deleted. The problem with your question is clarity: we need current, expected outputs and possibly any error trace.

Comment: so anyone can help my problems?

Comment: What do you mean by this `However, I can't wait the job is running, is there any missing step or syntax error?`. Is it not executing every day (except Sunday) at 22 hours?

Answer (score 0):

```
38 22 * * 0-6 cd /Users/mrcheung/Desktop/Python/Stock_Monitoring/ && python3 /Users/mrcheung/Desktop/Python/Stock_Monitoring/Stock_monitoring_students_v6_lesson_2020.py
```